# cx_freeze cannot find a dll I made

Tags: python, dll, cx-freeze

I have a problem with cx-freeze, it cannot load a dll I have created

my setup.py:

```
import sys
import clr
executablePath = 'E:\\PythonWS\\myWorkSpace\\'
sys.path.append(executablePath)
clr.AddReference("mydll")

print clr.FindAssembly('mydll')

import mydll
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

zhuli = mydll.fun()
zhuli.doTheThing()

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": [
                              'os', 'matplotlib.figure', 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg', 
                              'PyQt4.QtGui', 'PyQt4.Qt', 'sys'
                              ], 
                 "include_files": [
                                  'mydll', 
                                  ],
                 "excludes": [
                              'tkinter', 
                              ], 
                 'init_script':'Console'}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "guifoo",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "My GUI application!",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("test.py", base=base)])
```

This results with

```
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named mydll
```

although at the begining it prints:

```
E:\PythonWS\myWorkSpace\mydll.dll
```

And  `zhuli.doTheThing()` does the thing...

So to me that means it knows **where** the dll is, it can **access** it but doesnt want to **load** it for some reason. Anyone has an idea on this??

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
This is what i have in the `tmp.appcompat.txt` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="test.exe" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    ...
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="mydll.dll" SIZE="77824" CHECKSUM="0x5950C084" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="mydll" PRODUCT_NAME="mydll" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="mydll.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="mydll.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright ©  2012" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="07/01/2015 14:55:50" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/01/2015 14:55:50" VER_LANGUAGE="Independiente del idioma [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    ...
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="1114112" CHECKSUM="0x1325986C" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.19018" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.19018" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Archivo DLL de cliente API BASE de Windows NT" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Sistema operativo Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x11C776" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.19018" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.19018" LINK_DATE="09/29/2015 03:00:35" UPTO_LINK_DATE="09/29/2015 03:00:35" EXPORT_NAME="KERNEL32.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="Español (España, internacional) [0xc0a]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>`
```

EDIT 2:

After making a log, I realize that this is the `import clr` that is crashing the application

Anyone?

Comment: Shouldn't `mydll` in `include_files` be `mydll.dll`?

Comment: I tried both but they dont work

Comment: you can add full path to your file to the configuration in `include_files` like `C:\\some_path\\mydll.dll`

Comment: Well it did compile without errors (so thanks !) but in the end the .exe doesnt work..
When I dont use anything from mydll.dll in the `test.py` and the `setup.py` the .exe works fine

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should provide the *full path to your `.dll` file* in your settings:

```
"include_files": 
  [
        'mydll', 
  ]
```

Then, when your executable is constructed, you should make sure it can *'see'* your `dll`. Copy it into the directory where your executable is located and then launch the `.exe` file.

---

If some program uses some library (a `.dll` file in your case), it should *'know'* where to find it. There are special paths where this library is searched, including the path where the executable is located. If this library is missing, the app is likely to crash.

Comment: That is the problem:

- i did put the whole path (which worked to compile)

- `mydll.dll` already is in the folder where the `.exe` is

but it still doesnt work

Comment: Also, when I include the dll but does not use it in my `test.py` the executable crashes

Comment: @Drjnker, _how exactly_ doesn't it work? Crashes? Shows weird output?

Comment: I have a window saying "My GUI application! stopped working"
and with more details I can have access to the `tmp.appcompat.txt` (if it can be of any help?)

Comment: @Drjnker, certainly it can help since `"My application stopped working"` doesn't provide you with any details.

Comment: I edited my post with the content of the `tmp.appcompat.txt`